# Show that the given products are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

I'm trying to show that $$\frac{p^{n^2}(p^{n+1}-1)}{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})=\prod_{j=1}^n (p^{n+1}-p^{j-1})$$

I've started with the RHS and have done the following:

\begin{align*}\prod_{j=1}^n (p^{n+1}-p^{j-1}) & = p^{n(n+1)} \prod_{j=1}^n (1-p^{j-n-2}) \\ & = p^{n(n+1)} \prod_{j=1}^n (1-p^{-j-1})  \end{align*}

What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may continue by writing
$$
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^n (p^{n+1}-p^{j-1}) & = p^{n(n+1)} \prod_{j=1}^n (1-p^{-j-1})
\\ & = p^{n(n+1)} \prod_{j=2}^{n+1} (1-p^{-j})
\\ & = p^{n(n+1)} \frac{1-p^{-n-1}}{1-p^{-1}}\prod_{j=1}^{n} (1-p^{-j})
\\ & =\frac{p^{n(n+1)}\cdot p \cdot(p^{n+1}-1)}{p^{n+1}(p-1)}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})
\\ & = \frac{p^{n^2}(p^{n+1}-1)}{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})
\end{align*}
$$ as expected.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}p^{n(n+1)}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j-1})&=p^{n^2}p^n\frac{1-p^{-n-1}}{1-p^{-1}}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})\\&=p^{n^2}\frac{p^n-p^{-1}}{1-p^{-1}}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})\\&=p^{n^2}\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p^{-j})\end{align}$$

First step foiled the $n(n+1)$ and reindexed the product (try expanding a few terms to se what I did).

Second step distributes the $p^n$ to the fraction.

Last step multiplies the fraction by $\frac pp$.

Comment: Could you explain the reindexing please?

Comment: @user332597 Notice that the denominator is equal to the first term in the product, so it cancels.  The numerator would be the term that comes after the last term in the product, so multiply it into the product.  What do you have left?